# kendo.drawing.drawDOM leaks memory

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am .NET MVC developer.
I am working on a functionality which converts div element to pdf using kendo.drawing.drawDOM method and save to physical drive. This cycle repeats for at least 2000 times. But the problem is when counter reaches above 1700 chrome throws 'Google chrome ran out of memory exception'. I have researched on this issue and analysed that when I commented out code of converting div to pdf using kendo.drawing.drawDOM memory does not leak. So my guess is kendo.drawing.drawDOM method has memory leak issue. Below is a code reference.

[Code Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom)

Comment: See the note on Chrome at the bottom here. Maybe compression could help? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/pdf-output

Comment: Hi Steven,

Thanks for your reply. I included pako_deflate.min.js file in my application. But the issue not resolved yet. Is there any code to be written to use this library or just including library would work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Steve, adding pako_deflate.min.js reduces size of the pdf file but no change in memory leak.

Comment: You might have better luck on the [Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui/drawing-api)